# Custom post type disappeared in wordpress when I transferred theme to Showit

Tags: custom-post-types, blog

I'm working on a client website who had tons of custom blog post types. Once I changed the domain to direct to Showit theme, the custom blog posts are no longer editable or visible. Where did they go? How can I retrieve them and bring them back. She hadn't told me her blog posts were custom so I had no idea they would disappear. I can still see the posts exist under each "page" but I can't edit or access them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the custom post types were registered in the old theme then they will not be accessible from a different theme. You’d need to transfer the code that registered them to the new theme.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thank you. Once I transfer the code to the new theme, it would be accessible the same way as it was before? do you have any guidance or articles that would assist me in this? (p.s. my client doesn't know what theme she had before...)

Comment: With the information provided it's impossible to give more detail. Maybe, maybe not, it all depends on the implementation details. If you only copy over the code that registers the post types you could be missing things like the metaboxes and templates used to support additional custom fields, for example.